# Removing duplicates with multiple conditions via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report that saves displays in excel.  This report lists multiple time clock punches per employee/per day.
I need a way to clear out any duplicates between columns D and E, leaving only unique values.  Here's the catch, it needs to look at the specific employee for that day, then do this for each employee throughout the report (not looking at the previous day).  So if employee1 uses the time clock at 7:59 on Monday and Wednesday, it does not consider those to be duplicates.  I'm going to attempt to attach a screenshot of an example.  It only shows one day, but the actual report contains a week's worth of data.  Additionally, if there are two blank cells in columns D and E (side by side), the entire row needs to be deleted.
[image: Example Report]

Comment: There are SO many questions. Are time fields include seconds and many more.
A quick suggestion from a brief look is try a formula in column E
=IF(AND(D2="",E2=""),"Delete",IF(0.0001>ABS(D2 - E2),"Delete",""))
If D&E are blank or within a second of each other the result is "Delete" else ""

Answer (score 1):

Scan up the sheet comparing start time with previous line end time.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveDuplicates()

    Dim r As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 as long
    Dim d As Long, t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastrow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ' remove blank lines first
        For r = lastrow1 To 2 Step -1
            If Len(.Cells(r, "D") & Cells(r, "E")) = 0 Then
                .Rows(r).Delete
                d = d + 1
            End If
        Next
        
        lastrow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For r = lastrow2 To 3 Step -1
            ' compare with row above
            If (.Cells(r, "A") = .Cells(r - 1, "A")) And _
                  (.Cells(r, "C") = .Cells(r - 1, "C")) And _
                  (.Cells(r, "D") = .Cells(r - 1, "E")) Then
                  
                  ' update finish time line above
                  .Cells(r - 1, "E") = .Cells(r, "E")
                  .Rows(r).Delete
                  '.Rows(r).Interior.Color = vbRed
                  d = d + 1
            End If
            
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   
    MsgBox lastrow1 - 1 & " rows scanned" & vbLf & _
          d & " rows deleted", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")

End Sub
```

Comment: That's the correct functionality (tested).

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to do this without VBA, the simplest that I can think is this:

1. First, sort by Employee AND by Date.
2. Create two new columns (I will use F and G)
3. In the first new column and second line (F2), enter the formula:

```
=IF(OR(B2<>B1,C2<>C1,D2<>E1),D2,F1)
```

3. In the second column (G2), enter:

```
=IF(OR(B3<>B2,C3<>C2,D3<>E2),E2,G3)
```

4. Copy the formulas down.
5. You will see that the columns now contain the correct IN time and the correct OUT time.
6. Copy that and paste as values over the original.
7. Use the Data/Remove Duplicates feature to clean up.

Some explanation: the first column tests whether this is a new employee, using `B2<>B1`, whether this is a new date, using `C2<>C1`, and whether this IN time is different from the previous OUT time (`D2<>E2`). In all of these cases, adopt the IN time from this line (D2). Otherwise, the previous IN time (D1) is still valid.

The second column does almost the same, but it compares the employee, date and OUT time with the NEXT line. This way, we collect the last desired OUT time.

For the blank lines, I'd just use the autofilter to select them and delete manually.

You may try to save these steps as a macro, but I am not sure that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Pls try.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub DEMO()
    Dim rngData As Range, arrData, arrRes
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, RowCnt As Long, ColCnt As Long
    Dim resSht As Worksheet
    Dim sKey As String, sNewKey As String, iIndex As Long
    Dim StartRow As Long, EndRow As Long, LastTime2
    ' *** Modify as needed
    Const SOURCE_SHEET = "Data"
    Const OUPUT_SHEET = "Result"
    Const SEP_CHAR = "|"
    ' ***
    Const TIME2_COL = 5 ' Column E
    On Error Resume Next
    Set resSht = Sheets(OUPUT_SHEET)
    On Error GoTo 0
    ' Copy source table to output sheet
    If resSht Is Nothing Then
        Set resSht = Sheets(SOURCE_SHEET).Copy(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        resSht.Name = OUPUT_SHEET
    Else
        resSht.Cells.Clear
        With Sheets(SOURCE_SHEET)
            .Range(.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Copy resSht.Range("A1")
        End With
    End If
    ' Sort source table on output sheet
    With resSht
    Set rngData = .Range(.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With
    ' Modify column header as needed
    rngData.Sort key1:="Emp ID", order1:=xlAscending, key2:="Date", _
        order2:=xlAscending, key3:="Time1", _
        order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    With rngData
        arrData = rngData.Resize(.Rows.Count + 1).Value
    End With
    RowCnt = UBound(arrData)
    ColCnt = UBound(arrData, 2)
    ReDim arrRes(1 To RowCnt, 1 To ColCnt)
    ' Table header
    For j = 1 To ColCnt
        arrRes(1, j) = arrData(1, j)
    Next j
    iIndex = 2: StartRow = 2
    ' Initial process
    sKey = arrData(2, 1) & SEP_CHAR & arrData(2, 3)
    LastTime2 = arrData(2, 4)
    For i = 2 To RowCnt
        If Len(arrData(i, 4) & arrData(i, 5)) > 0 Or Len(arrData(i, 1)) = 0 Then
            sNewKey = arrData(i, 1) & SEP_CHAR & arrData(i, 3)
            ' [EmpID+Date change] OR [Current Time1 <> Last Time2]
            If sNewKey <> sKey Or Abs(arrData(i, TIME2_COL - 1) - LastTime2) > 0.0000001 Then
                For j = 1 To ColCnt
                    arrRes(iIndex, j) = arrData(StartRow, j)
                Next j
                arrRes(iIndex, TIME2_COL) = arrData(EndRow, TIME2_COL)
                iIndex = iIndex + 1
                StartRow = i
                sKey = arrData(i, 1) & SEP_CHAR & arrData(i, 3)
            End If
            LastTime2 = arrData(i, TIME2_COL)
            EndRow = i
        End If
    Next i
    ' Write data
    With resSht.Range("A1")
        .CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        .Resize(RowCnt, ColCnt).Value = arrRes
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately they only gave me "part" of the report which led me astray.  It's actually much more complicated (I'm going to leave a link to the full thing).  I've created a macro to do the sorting and insert lines between different dates, now I need to eliminate duplicate times for each of the groupings.  https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/x2725bdjexrch9mf4ei29/example.xlsm?rlkey=e6dr2qqolqijhkcggpvb4xooj&dl=0

Comment: Is `insert lines`  must-have? Please share your data with markdown table and code in OP. Downloading unknown xlsm is risky.

Comment: I'm sorry, markdown?  As far as the blank lines, I was just attempting to create a gap between dates and personnel in an effort to make the times easier to manipulate, it wouldn't be mandatory if it can be done without the blanks.

Comment: The revised code will capture all data regardless of the presence of blank rows, although the blank rows are unnecessary.

Comment: About markdown https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, it may be helpful for you to post questions.